# Which ports should I open for apt-get to work?

Tags: apt, iptables, firewall, webmin

I installed Webmin, and then set up the firewall like this:

```
INPUT
SSH port ALLOWED
Webmin port ALLOWED
HTTP port (80) ALLOWED
DROP EVERYTHING ELSE

FORWARDING
no rules

OUTPUT
no rules
```

If I remove `DROP EVERYTHING ELSE` from INPUT, everything works.

However, when that rule is added, apt-get doesn't work, and I can't `ping` or `traceroute` anything.

Even with `DROP EVERYTHING ELSE` enabled, Webmin, HTTP and SSH still work.

Which ports should I unblock to get apt-get working and allowed connecting to other domains from within the server?

Thanks

Comment: Try port 22 or 21

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you accept also connection originated from inside. With iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

With Webmin, allow

```
Connection states EQUALS Existing Connection
```

Comment: Hello, this works fine.Thanks!

P.S. to do this on Webmin (for anyone who finds this on Google) you need to choose "Connection states EQUALS Existing Connection"

Answer (score 2):

You should have port 80 for TCP and 53 for UDP in INPUT enabled

```
-A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 --dport 1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score -1):

For me on Ubuntu 22 @Miroslav Oprsteny and @Yam Gotham answers get worked with this

```
iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Here is [original post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1153930)